# Evitar un fallo en Jenkins al reiniciar servicios con Powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Estoy intentando realizar una automatización en la que se paran servicios de una lista de servidores, se realizan algunas tareas, y después se reinician los servicios, todo esto en Powershell lanzado desde Jenkins.
Todo va bien hasta que llega a la parte de reiniciar los servicios, aquí algunos fallan, y, como difiere en cada servidor, no excluyo servicios para tener el script generalizado. Y al fallar el iniciar algún servicio hace que falle la build.

¿Hay manera de evitar que tome estos errores como fallo en la build? (lo mismo es alguna tontería que no estoy viendo)

Aquí el código:

```
# credenciales
$password = convertto-securestring -String $env:password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $env:TheUsername, $password

Foreach($server in $ENV:servers){
    $connectiontest = Test-Connection $server -Quiet
    if($connectiontest -eq $true){
        Ivoke-Command -Computername "$server" -Credential $cred -ErrorVariable InvokeErrorMessage -ScriptBlock{

            Stop-Service XXXX*
            # Aquí va el resto de cosas que se hacen
            try{
                Restart-Service XXXX*
            }
            Catch{
                Write-Output "Algunos servicios no se inician, pasando..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me contesto a mi mismo, y lo dejó por aquí por si alguien se pregunta lo mismo. Era tan obvio que ni lo veía. Con añadir `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` después del `Restart-Service XXXX*` funciona.
Si es que a estas horas ya la cabeza va como va.